# Syntax for storing one array value as variable

Tags: ios, arrays, sqlite

In designing a quiz app I want to compare the answer selected by the user to the correct answer in an sqlite array.

To do this, I want to do the following on `viewDidLoad:`, load up the correct answer (which is an integer 1,2,3 etc.) and store it as `qACorrect` variable.

Then on `- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender` to have it compare the variable `qACorrect` with `qASelected`

Could someone help me with the syntax for assigning the value of `qACorrect` which is imported in the array to the new variable `qACorrect`? I am using the rest of this code on ViewDidLoad to load up the questions:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MySjtQuestionslist * MySJT =[[MySjtQuestionslist alloc] init];
    self.SJT = [MySJT getMySjtQuestion];
    [self.QuestionText setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestion];
    [self.labelA setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionA];
    [self.labelB setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionB];
    [self.labelC setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionC];
    [self.labelD setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionD];
    [self.labelE setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionE];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES]; //scrollview stuff
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)]; //scrollview stuff
}
```

Comment: can you show what you are doing in "submit method"?

Comment: Why are there multiple questions; shouldn't there be multiple answers instead?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. There is one main question text at the top then 5 subsections of that question. The answers are selected by using a 1-5 option (Segmented Control) as they need to be ranked in order of probability 1-5.

Comment: My submit method is not finished yet, but in principle: I want something like this 
`if (qAVariable = qACorrect) {
        score = score + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        score = score - 1;
        
    }` 

Where qAVariable is the value selected from the segmented controller, and repeated for the other B-E questions.

Comment: So how do you know (as the coder) which question is correct?

Comment: Because I will compare each answer to the answer from the database. qACorrect only applies to question A. qBCorrect is for B etc.. I only wanted the syntax for one and then I could modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that **qAVariable is the value selected from the segmented controller.** & **qACorrect is of NSString Type**,

You don't need to implement an extra "submit" method. On segment value change, you can do this.

```
- (IBAction)onSegmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender 
{
     NSString *selAnswer= [sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];

     if ([selAnswer isEqualToString:qACorrect])
     {
         score = score + 1;    
     }   
     else  
     {         
         score = score - 1;
     }
}
```

**Update:**
for getting integer value, use this:

```
int qACorrect= [[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]] intValue];
```

Let me know if more info needed..

Comment: Thanks. But I want a submit button because I want to allow the user the opportunity to change his mind before submission. However, the problem I am having is assigning a variable to qACorrect in the first place. You are right that qAVariable is the value selected from the segmented controller. qACorrect however is an NSInteger. I don't know how to write a syntax to grab that integer value from the sqlite array `getMySjtQuestion` and assign it to qACorrect. The code I included above grabs the values and assigns them to labels. How do I change it so the values are assigned to a variable instead?

Comment: So, to use this line as an example:

`[self.labelA setText:((SjtQuestionlist *) [self.SJT objectAtIndex:0]).SJTQuestionA];` this loads the value from SJTQUestionA and displays it in labelA.

How do I write a syntax that loads the integer value from SJTCorrectA and stores it in the integer variable qACorrect?

Comment: @medictrader [[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex] intValue] will give you intValue. now assign it to any variable of int type.. Check my updates in answer